# Soundproof basement and bedroom vents

Tags: sound-proofing, sounds

I'm in the process of finishing my basement. Added rocksaul to the ceiling and you can still hear everything in the basement through the vents. How do you soundproof a vent in a basement so that the sound doesn't go through the vents. While still allowing air to go through and heat the house?

Comment: More info need, type of pipe vent? Size? Is it just carrying sound from one room? Or the whole basement? Can you hear it through all the vents or just from one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We line the ducts with “ductboard” insulation and use sound baffles. Often we’re concerned about hearing the  sound of the fan coming on or turning off. We’ll use sound baffles to block the clicking sound from traveling down the duct. However, we usually “up size” the ducts to accommodate the added “blockage” in the duct.

Also, we design the system so no two vent/grille openings are too close together without sound having to travel about 10’ - 12’ before coming out the next vent.

Comment: Thanks @lee sam. I ended up not needing to do anything. Once the drywall was added, it gave another layer of sound protection, coupled with the Roxul. You can kind of hear through the duct work but not as much so I'm calling it a day : )